# Using subjects in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

My **main.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  private mainSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  main$ = this.mainSource.asObservable();
}
```

My **app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private appService: AppService){
  this.appService.main$.subscribe(
  working => {this.appService.main$(false);}
}

ngOnInit(){
    if (this.appService.main$){alert("Tio");}
}
```

My app.component returns a `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature` error. And my OnInit alert fires regardless of whether or not the conditions have actually been met. In this case they have not.

Subscriptions are still quite foreign to me, so I'm not clear on exactly what I should be doing here. I want to set my `main$` to an initial value of false. And when my page is loaded, I would like it to alert only if it is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change values on a Subject it is best to create a separate method for that. In this case I added a `setWorking` method to change the Subject's boolean value.

Next, the component subscribes to the Subject (which is returned as an Observable) and listens to changes to the value.

If the value changes, the callback function inside the `subscribe` block will be invoked.

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  private mainSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  main$ = this.mainSource.asObservable();

  setWorking(isWorking: boolean) {
    this.mainSource.next(isWorking);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
private subscription: Subscription

constructor(private appService: AppService){ }

ngOnInit(){

  this.appService.setWorking(false);

  this.subscription = this.appService.main$.subscribe(isWorking => {
    if (isWorking) { alert("Tio"); }
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

At last, you could add a `this.appService.setWorking(true);` function call after the subscription, to have the alert show up.

PS: I have added the `ngOnDestroy` part, since the subscription is not automatically cleared when navigating away and  thus would create a memory leak. You need to import `Subscription` from `rxjs/Subscription`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are subscribing in the constructor. So you do not know when the result comes, because it is async. In the meantime, the constructor finished immediately and the OnInit is invoked.

I don't know how your service looks like, but it would be the best if you also subscribe to an event in the OnInit method.

Comment: This isn't right. Observables are not asynchronous *unless their work requires them to be*. In other words, if an observable fetches data remotely, it will execute asynchronously. But if it just passes through a value that was set on a `Subject`, it will happen synchronously. That's the case here. The problem with the OP is what @Alexander wrote. [The manual states](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observables-as-generalizations-of-functions): *Some people claim that Observables are asynchronous. That is not true.*