# How send data from a component to a Module?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a component where I have `flagPerfil` variable, I need to send this variable to my module.

my service

```
export class ListUserService {
    public flagPerfil = boolean;
    changeFlagPerfil() {
        console.log('EEE' + this.flagPerfil);
        this.flagPerfil ? this.flagPerfil = false : this.flagPerfil = true;
    }
```

**component class:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-list-user',
    templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.scss'],
    providers: [ListUserService]
})
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
    private flagPerfil = false;

    getFlag() {
        return this.flagPerfil;
    }
```

This is the view **list-user.component.html**

```
<span *ngIf="!flagPerfil">
  <input type="button" id="usuarios" name="more" (click)="changeFlagPerfil()"
    value="Amigos">
</span>
```

I have a module, I want to inject the service in the module, because 
I need the `FlagProfile` variable

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: Tab1Page}])
    ],
    declarations: [Tab1Page, ListUserComponent, FriendsComponent]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {
    public flagPerfil: boolean;

    constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {
        this.flagPerfil = listUserService.flagPerfil;
        console.log('FLAG', listUserService.flagPerfil);
    }
}
```

How do I use an event Emit?

I need the module to automatically hear the changes of that variable

Comment: Don't use modules like services. I don't see why this needs to be done in the constructor.

Comment: @Reactgular i need to use module, i need the value of flagPerfil

Comment: @Reactgular 
I do not use the module as a service, I have a service for the component

Answer (score 1):

```
export class ListUserService {
    public flag$ = new Subject< boolean >();

}


export class Tab1PageModule {
    public flagPerfil: boolean;

    constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {
        listUserService.$flags.subscribe((flag)=>{
           console.log('FLAG', flag;
           this.flagPerfil = flag;
      });

    }
}


export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {
    private flagPerfil = false;

    getFlag() {
        return this.flagPerfil;
    }


    constructor(private listUserService: ListUserService) {

    }
    functionThatGetsCalledWhenTheFlagIsChanged(){
       this.listUserService.flags$.next(this.flagPerfil);

     }

}
```

Comment: whe i use this functionThatGetsCalledWhenTheFlagIsChanged?

Comment: flagPerfil is boolean

Comment: i get this error  error TS2322: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Subject<{}>'.

Comment: @yaha you serious ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the type to the Subject as shown in [this](https://link.medium.com/dxF2KnRI4W) tutorial for Subject, e.g. `= new Subject<boolean>();`

A similar question was asked [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337891/using-subjects-in-angular-2&ved=2ahUKEwiBk8PT7L_iAhVCQKwKHQRNCnkQjjgwAHoECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw16jUbLE6ruvOFIA5XoEizs)

Update: I fixed the formatting, which was preventing `<boolean>` from being displayed